# Keyword Densities - do they still matter?

Tags: seo

Let's say I have a standard issue web page with 500 - 600 words and I'm priming my page for two specific keywords (for the purposes of this example). We know that these words need to feature within the context of the page but how many times should they be used in the body text? How many times is too many? How few is too little? Does it even make any difference any more? Conventionally I have learned and used 2 to 7 % density and typically I've seen SEO organisations use roughly 4 % density for two word phrases.

If I want this page to perform well in the search engines what are the best practises in relation to densities? What strategies have worked for you on real world projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms **keywords density DOES matter** for Google ranking, you can easy test it by creating two identical pages indexed exactely once from the same page (just to let Google know they exist and index them).
Then in one you place tow/three times more the keyword/keyphrase, than in the other one. You will see the 1st one will rank high maybe just one position, but still high.

**Keywords stuffing does NOT matter in my own experience**, and even if it matters it's bad SEO practice so it might result in penalizing your site, why risking that?!

Comment: +1 A pragmatic answer. Although my original question was not asking how to keyword stuff. Everybody knows that is a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Keyword stuffing has been abused so much that Google will penalize sites where keywords are repeated too much, tracking keyword density is not useless - it is actually harmful.

- The most valuable locations on page are the page title and the h1 tag - make sure to use the keywords there.
- Repeat the keywords in the page text maybe 2-3 more times.
- Use synonyms - this will both prevent Google from penalizing you for keyword stuffing and get you some more "long tail" searches.
- Write for humans not for search engines - after all, the whole point of getting someone to the site is to get that someone to take some action - don't get so obsessed about SEO that you forget that (SEO-heavy text is likely to make people immediately reach for the back button)

Comment: Your last point is the most vital. Trying to shoehorn keywords into places they're not wanted leads to *terrible writing* and low-quality content.

Comment: Good answer, but please note my question wasn't about how to get away with keyword stuffing. It is more so aimed at sensible approaches with density/ratio/none people are using to construct their web pages.

Comment: @BradB: If you start paying the slightest attention to keyword density you are already keyword stuffing. Just write naturally and relevant keywords will appear in the page from good writing.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: You said just write "naturally", that's the basis of this question. What is the definition of natural? How would a search engine define what is natural/un-natural?

Comment: @BradB: Writing naturally is writing content for users, not search engines, and not thinking about things like keyword density. If you just write good content (or hire an exceptional writer to write exceptional content), then you'll have a "natural" keyword density. I mean, if Google _does_ prefer an ideal keyword density, how do you think they'd arrive at those figures? Probably by finding the median keyword density on pages with high quality content. So there's no point in trying to explicitly "optimize" your keyword density.

Comment: @BradB - writing naturally is not writing to satisfy statistics, search engines look for keyword stuffing (among other things) and filter out "bad" pages, the algorithms are secret and nobody here knows the exact formula. the best way to avoid those penalties is to write the page you want your customer/user/reader to see after arriving at the site and not to write the page for search engines (of course, you should cover the basics like titles and h1)

Comment: @Lèse majesté: I don't know how Google would arrive at those figures and I too think they would likely find the median of good quality pages, hence this question. I'm curious to see what other SEOers are doing. May I ask that you elaborate on why you feel there is not point trying to explicitly optimise? There is a huge industry chasing and using optimisation theories. Are they wasting their time?

Comment: @BradB: There is a huge industry doing SEO, but not on optimizing keyword densities. In fact, most leading SEO firms (e.g. SEOmoz) do not aim for a particular keyword density and discourage its use as an SEO metric. Secondly, what is this obsession of yours with micro-optimizations? Is it that you cannot generate quality content? Or perhaps you feel that micro-optimizations which provide no value to users and negatively impact content quality is the sign of a true SEO?

Comment: It just seems to me like you're itching to do things the hard way. Instead of focusing on the handful of SEO factors known to have the most influence on ranking, you want to go after the hundreds of micro-optimizations based on speculation over minor algorithm quirks that would have negligible impact on ranking at best. Google and everyone else is telling you "just eat healthy and you won't need to take vitamin supplements", but you keep asking "how many vitamin tablets is equivalent to a healthy diet?" You just seem set on fighting search engines and overoptimizing your sites.

Comment: @Lèse majesté: So in your opinion, densities and proximities are useless? I'm not fighting the search engines (or you). To date, most people I encounter believe in densities and proximities. So I'm asking why, in your experiences they don't matter so much? Have you made stuff rank with 0.0001% ratio for specific words? I know the Google guidelines contain sensible advice about being "decent" in SEO terms, but that doesn't necessarily mean densities and proximities don't get results in the real world. Does it?

Comment: Keep in mind that most people still think meta tags affect their rankings and that .edu pages get a boost in the SERPs. So most people believing in magic numbers for keyword density isn't saying anything positive. And Google bombing shows how keyword density can be meaningless. At one point a keyword density of 0% could rank #1 if enough links pointed to that page with the right anchor text. Google changed that only slightly by requiring any word of the Google Bomb to be present on the page. That's still a small %, certainly less then 1%.

Comment: @BradB: Yes. A 0.0001% ratio isn't hard to achieve if you have a reasonably useful/usable site. And term weight is the closest thing to keyword densities that most SEOs believe search engines make _some_ use of. However, the reason that most leading SEOs don't bother with keyword density or tf-idf weight is that it's a very minor factor these days for which there's no evidence showing it can boost your ranking. The most effect it has on SEO is as a negative factor for over-optimized sites.

Comment: @BradB - I have pages that ranked #1 on Google with just a single mention of the keywords, and a lot more pages on the first page for keywords I never targeted explicitly, at the end of the day what makes you rank is the number and quality of links to your site - keyword density plays no role what so ever in ranking except if you get penalized for keyword stuffing (and you are unlikely to get penalized for keyword stuffing if you don't measure keyword density simply because good readable content is not that keyword-rich)

Comment: @Nir: You say "keyword density plays no role what so ever in ranking". That's exactly what I'm trying to establish. If you can offer a reliable resource (preferably with some real world examples) to back this up then I will happily mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: And if you're not trying to fight the search engines, then why not do what they want you to do and just don't artificially manipulate keyword densities? (Also, why the condescending attitude towards following Google recommendations?) Why not let the search engine work for you instead of pursuing SEO strategies which put you in direct conflict with the direction that search engines are moving in? You're doing exactly what Google doesn't want you to do and what they're constantly updating their algorithm to combat.

Comment: @BradB - you want a reliable source and real world examples, you won't get reliable sources in this topic, the search engine junk sites fighting algorithms are secret and change all the time, they don't give any details because if they did spammers could easily adapt, as for real world examples, I can't give you any (except for my blog ranking high for all sort of random low competition keywords I mentioned only once) and even if I did, you can never be sure ranking changes are due to keywords densities or a random Google algorithm change that happened that week.

Comment: @BradB - everyone here except you seems to think keyword densities doesn't matter and shouldn't be tracked, there is a lot of junk information about SEO out there - and you can even still find sites telling you the meta keywords tag is important, so it's understandable that one of us is wrong, if you want high-quality SEO data you will have to join a good and expensive site like seobook.com (where you will find experienced people that may share real world examples but even they don't have inside info on Google) - or we can just agree to disagree.

Comment: @Nir: In my original question, if out of the 500 words 100 of them were comprised of the same keyword, would that result in a penalty? And why does spamming get pulled into this? Nobody here wants to spam, it's a short term win at best. I'm mean practical use of moving a few words around. How how much is too much when using a word. I keep hearing "you don't need to" and "stop thinking like a spammer", but this never comes with any practical reason to back it up other than a referral to the Google documentation - which is a guideline which I often see violated on high ranking pages.

Comment: @BradB - I can't answer that question because I don't work at Google and I don't know exactly what and how they penalize, if I did know I wouldn't be able to answer at all because of an NDA - so no one here will ever be able to answer that question,  however,  I have heard about sites being penalized for less than that and what i do know is that text where every fifth word is a repeated keyword is painful to read.

Comment: @BradB - (continue from last comment) - to summarize: 1. I understand your question 2. you will never get the answer to this question 3. what everyone here is trying to tell you is that you is that the question itself is irrelevant and you are asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword density is close to irrelevant, as evinced by the success of so-called [Google bombing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb) *across most major search engines* - links (and links' anchor text) matter more than on-site content; it doesn't hurt to use the keywords you want to rank for across your site, but the density is far less important than incoming links.

Comment: Google has made many changes to tackle Google Bombing, and it's not as prevalent as it once was.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - By all appearances, (and as alluded to in the linked Wikipedia article) Google is correcting bombs on a case-by-case basis. For example: http://www.google.com/search?q=french+military+victories&btnI=I&#39;m%20Feeling%20Lucky

Comment: The google bomb solution seems to be algorithmic as George Bush's web page reappeared at #1 "miserable failure" after the word "failure" appeared on it again.

Comment: @John_Conde - Either my coffee isn't working or something was lost in translation - can you clarify what you mean? How did you arrive at the determination that Google is algorithmically filtering for bombs? (... and how does that explain "french military victories" as an active Google bomb?)

Comment: There's a blog post about our algorithmic handling of "Google bombs" at http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/01/quick-word-about-googlebombs.html -- but all in all, I think "Google bombs" is not really relevant to a question about keyword density :). Regarding keyword density, as mentioned by @DisgruntledGoat, that's not really something worth focusing on.

Comment: @John Mueller: You say density is "not really worth focusing on". Why? That's the basis of this question. Why not? Is it not important in the  slightest? A little bit? "Not really worth focusing" is a pretty big claim made as a minor passing statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated view for 2014 with a brief historical explanation.

In the early days of search engines, Google seems to be the focus here and so I will speak to Google, the methods of determining the site and page subject was to evaluate several things from the links to a page, the `title` tag, the header tags primarily the `h1` tag, for a period the `description` meta-tag, and the content particularly the top about 200k (or so no one really knew for sure) of text for clues. Later, the entire text was examined. The only real mechanism was to measure the number of words found on a particular page and HTML elements and weigh them accordingly to determine a topic by recognizing words, phrases, and associating them with other uses to identify the topic. With this, the strength of the supposed topic was weighed using the literal count of the recognizable topic keywords and phrases. But since Google used machine learning methods, anything not easily recognizable would be simply weighed by word count at the very least. This was a good method for a time.

Then came the various methods of gaming this system.

In 2008 with the introduction of Scholar, Google realized the value of citations and began to recognize the power of hidden connections in documents not recognized before. This caused a shift in how Google would ultimately recognize topics and value of content. Scholar, as it existed, was moved into the regular Google algorithms and a shift from traditional weighting to something more analytical focusing on relationships and recognizable patterns in context began to take shape. This was a process that evolved and improved significantly over a number of years.

There is an argument over whether keyword density was ever really a factor thus raising the notion that *keyword density was a myth*. Both sides of the argument had merits. For a while, it was necessary to maintain a certain keyword density to compete, but too much density was 1: easily recognized for what it was, and 2: counter productive yielding in too little gain if any. The magic number has been argued of course. For a keyword to achieve an appropriate density to properly be recognized as having value would vary radically depending upon the number of words on the page leaving open speculation as to what density was optimal for any word. The fact of the matter was, that for any word to achieve the recommended percentage density (according to SEO experts at the time), the word would have to used an inordinate number of times. The longer the page, the more ridiculous the word count would have to be.

But now the game has changed.

After much earned criticisms and some not so well deserved, Google found it's way into removing keyword density as a factor though some elements of the original algorithm will seem familiar.

Keyword density is no longer a factor though keywords remain important. Instead of density, usage of keywords in links, `title` tags, `h1` tags (as well as other header tags), and throughout content has become important. But because citation indexing is more prevalent and has matured to such a high state, a more natural writing of the content is now required. Each word is evaluated within context to other words, some by proximity and others by relational word/phrase indexing, so that the topic and value of a page can be better determined if and only if the content was written to be read by humans and not evaluated by machines. Google moved from evaluating content like a machine exclusively with mathematical algorithms to evaluating content closer to how humans actually evaluate content which was the goal. In short, these days, even if you were to get away with it, keyword density actually has no place in how content is evaluated anymore. Sure there are some *gotchas* and bumps along the road. No system is perfect. But it is improving.