# Rank Ordered List of Words on a Web Page?

Tags: seo

I want (for purposes of SEO) to read a web page URL using some tool and get back the text only (no markup) words on that page, in rank order, with the most frequently occurring word first, like this:

`a          120
an         100
the        42
lawn       32
landscape  22
aardvark   1`

This is such a mind-bogglingly useful thing to want that I'm astonished that I can't find such a tool.  Does such a thing exist? My question is about the existence of a keyword density tool, not about which one is "best" nor about keyword stuffing, which I know is bad.

Google's advice, from their Webmaster blog, is "Search engine optimization includes things as simple as keyword research to ensure that the right words are on the page, not just industry jargon that normal people will never type." http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/04/another-step-to-reward-high-quality.html

I'm trying to help a friend who runs a lawn service.  It turns out the site's main page talks about "landscape maintenance" and not "lawn service."  It needs to be rewritten using vocabulary searchers are likely to use.  A tool such as was identified in the accepted answer will help me find those things over the site's dozen or so pages.

Comment: This is my first question here.  I really did look hard for answers first.  If I've messed up, please be somewhat gentle.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters. Unfortunately this question will primarily result in [recommendations](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for tools, which is off-topic for this site since that tends to result in spam and self-promotional answers. Please feel free to ask other questions here about webmastering in the future though.

Comment: Note that you could edit this question to ask something like: "_Is measuring keyword density still helpful for SEO?_" instead to get feedback on that before investing more time on it, which would add the question back into the review queue for reopening.

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  I got the answer I wanted from closetnoc.  I am very willing to edit my question if it will help others, but only if that will really help others.

Comment: Edited to add: If I can help others, I want to do that.  If what I write just makes moderators make the same decision again, well, that doesn't seem useful.  Guidance will be appreciated, and probably taken.

Comment: No problem, just didn't want you feel put-off by the hold. Unfortunately we have guidelines we have to stick to so that the site doesn't get subverted and become a beacon for ads. I'm reviewing some questions to see if that might possibly end-up getting closed as a duplicate...if not, would you like me edit it for you, so that it also still fits with closetnoc's answer?

Comment: After some review, it seems that also might get closed as a duplicate of [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/keyword-densities-do-they-still-matter/3985#3985) question. See the comment by John Mueller (from Google) there: `Regarding keyword density...that's not really something worth focusing on` (from as far back as 2010). Hope to see you here again though!

Comment: If not closed as duplicate, please do edit it, and thank you.

Comment: I've edited the question (several times!) the better to reflect what such a tool is good for, even though "keyword density" doesn't work and keyword stuffing is penalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a keyword density tool. The best free one is: http://tools.seobook.com/general/keyword-density/ which allows one page at a time. I prefer ranks.nl which costs a monthly fee. It is far superior to all the rest and definitely worth the fee if you are in the business.

As a side note. Keyword density in regard to SEO is a myth. It is still a valuable discovery tool to really know what any page is about.

I know that there is a focus on keywords, which are important, and where and how to manipulate search using keywords. The reality is, those days are gone and never really existed the way SEO professionals liked you to believe. Today, there is a simple formula to follow and knowing how to focus your writing toward your audience. This is where keywords are important. Are you really targeting a specified audience? I use keyword density tools to know what any page I have written is really about so I know how to adjust (slightly) the page and how to present it. Not how to keyword load or manipulate my way into the SERPs.

Comment: Thanks.  I think, hope, and expect, that I'm using keyword density to see what a page is really about, but then to rewrite as necessary to make "really about" and "supposed to be about" be congruent.  Thanks also for telling me about "keyword density."  That's not what I had been looking for.

Comment: @BobBrown Welcome to the site. There are some really great people here and some real experts. One of the things I see here based upon the questions is the vastness of misinformation in regard to SEO. I use keyword density tools to guide my work and to discover hidden gems within my natural writings. It is an excellent tool for this. I love ranks.nl, but it is no longer free. Bummer! I write about this process and always recommend natural writing over being overly focused. Sure focus. But do not put too much of a preconceived notion of what your page is about before it is written. ;-)

Comment: @dan If you want to mark this as a duplicate as you thought, that would be alright by me.